# Generic CRUD operations using Slick 2.0

Tags: scala, crud, slick, slick-2.0

I am trying to write a generic CRUD trait for Slick 2.0. The trait should **a)** provide generic methods to read/update/delete entities as well as **b)** abstract from the database. Following [this slick example](https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/MultiDBCakeExample.scala) (database abstraction) and [this article](http://crisdev.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/crud-trait-for-slick-2-0/) (CRUD trait) I came up with the following (shortened) code snippet:

```
trait Profile {
  val profile: JdbcProfile
}

trait Crud[T <: AbstractTable[A], A] { this: Profile =>
  import profile.simple._

  val qry: TableQuery[T]

  def countAll()(implicit session: Session): Int = {
    qry.length.run
  }

  def getAll()(implicit session: Session): List[A] = {
      qry.list // <-- type mismatch; found: List[T#TableElementType] required: List[A]
  }
}
```

The code is invalid due to a type mismatch. The return type of the 2nd function seems to be of type `List[T#TableElementType]` but needs to be List[A]. Any ideas on how to solve the issue. Additional references to further readings on generic Slick 2.0 operations are welcome too.

Comment: It works if you use `Table` instead of `AbstractTable`, but for that, you need a concrete `Profile`. I'm confused how profiles in slick 2.0 are intended to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type TableElementType` is abstract inside of `class AbstractTable[A]`. Scala doesn't know about any relationship between `A` and `TableElementType`. `class Table` on the other hand defines `final type TableElementType = A`, which tells Scala about this relationship (and apparently Scala is smart enough to use the `final` annotation to know that the relationanship even holds for a subtype `T <: Table[A]` eventhough `Table[A]` is not co-variant in `A`).

So you need to use `T <: Table[A]` instead of `T <: AbstractTable[A]`. And because `Table` is inside the Slick driver cake (as in cake pattern), you need to move your Crud into your cake as well. Cakes are viral.

```
trait Profile {
  val profile: JdbcProfile
}
trait CrudComponent{ this: Profile =>
  import profile.simple._

  trait Crud[T <: Table[A], A] {

    val qry: TableQuery[T]

    def countAll()(implicit session: Session): Int = {
      qry.length.run
    }

    def getAll()(implicit session: Session): List[A] = {
        qry.list // <-- works as intended
    }
  }
}
```