# Generic AutoIncInsert in slick

Tags: scala, generics, slick-2.0

Let's say I want to have an ID columen in all my case classes that I will use with slick:

```
abstract class BaseEntity(val _id:Option[Long])
case class SomeEntity(id:Option[Long],value:String) extends BaseEntity(id)
```

Now let's define the abstract class for the scheme and a real scheme:

```
  abstract class BaseScheme[A  <: BaseEntity](tag:Tag,name:String) extends Table[A](tag,name) {
    def id = column[Long]("ID",O.PrimaryKey,O.AutoInc)
  }
  class SomeEntityScheme(tag:Tag) extends BaseScheme[SomeEntity](tag,"SOME_NAME") {
    def value = column[String]("value",O.NotNull)
    def * = (id.?,value) <> (SomeEntity.tupled,SomeEntity.unapply)
  }

  val someEntitiesTable = TableQuery[SomeEntityScheme]
```

Now since I thought that I'm bored with writing the AutoIncInsert method I will create a generic one and this is the moment where I fall short:

```
 object BaseScheme {
     def autoIncInsert[T <: BaseScheme[_]] (t : TableQuery[T]) = t returning t.map(_.id) into {case (p,id) => p.copy(id = Some(id))}
  }
```

and of course the output of problem:

```
[error] /home/tomaszk/Projects/4.4/mCloud/application/service-execution/execution-provisioning-model/src/main/scala/pl/mlife/mcloud/provisioning/database/schemes/ExcludingServicesScheme.scala:48: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scala.slick.ast.TypedType[T#TableElementType]
[error]      def remap[T <: BaseScheme[_]] (t : TableQuery[T]) = t returning t.map(_.id) into {case (p,id) => p.copy(id = Some(id))}
[error]                                                                                                       ^
[error] one error found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be possible with your approach, I don't have enough knowledge to say it can't, but it sounds a bit fishy and overly complicated. What I did was using the same approach I used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345303/slick-2-0-generic-crud-operations/23395205#23395205), that is define a method that takes a `T#TableElementType` (that would be a row object) and a `TableQuery` object and do some generic operations:

```
def autoIncInsert[T <: BaseScheme[_]](row: T#TableElementType, tableReference: TableQuery[T])(implicit s: Session) = {
  (tableReference returning tableReference.map(_.id)) += row
}
```

Then as type `T` you should pass `SomeEntityScheme` class.

This should solve your problem in a more coincise and simple way in my opinion.

Comment: I have a great talent for "engineering" overly complicated solutions sometimes ;). Thank you for helping. This was exactly what I needed.