# append query clause in a functional compositional way

Tags: scala, slick

system that we're building is a multi tenant. there is a `subject` that each request will have and part of subject it'll have a `tenantId` in there.

Now when querying data all slick queries need to have a filter condition as

`slickTableQueryObj.filter(_.tenantId === subject.tenantId)`

it's a repetitive code in all the queries for all `slickTableQueryObj`. also it really shouldn't be developer's responsibility to remember to add this `tenantId` filter when writing slick queries - hence a need to abstract that way and programmatically add this filter for all the queries. What's the best way to kind of `inject` this filter clause ?

Comment: Simply abstract the filter in a method where you pass the tenant id and return the result so that you can chain other functions to it.

Comment: how to go about generalizing `slickTableQueryObj` and it's property `tenantId` ? so generalized abstracted method works for all `slick` tableObjects ?

Comment: You can extend a common class which has a column `tenantId` instead of `Table`, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345303/slick-2-0-generic-crud-operations) self answer I posted some time ago for an example, especially the part on `RichTable`, my common column was `id`.

Comment: thanks. in that linked post I see that you too are using slick code generator. and with custom abstract `RichTable`. how did you tell code generator to extend 'RichTable` for "selected" set of generated slick class ?

Comment: I did it by hand, for me it was not worth spending time to tell the code generator how to do that, probably if you post that as a question somebody will answer.