# What are the way/s of telling scala compiler that type TableQuery[T] can map to somthing has the attribute id

Tags: scala, slick

I want the compiler to know or to test if, that type T having a property id.

```
def del[T](id: Int) = TableQuery[T] filter (_.id === id) delete
```

Comment: Is your question answered? Consider accepting the most helpful answer.

Comment: No, not answered!

Comment: I see 4 answers here. Care to comment what doesn't work of what's still unclear? You could also leave comments to the contributors answering to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @maasg It is very clear from Ende Neu answer, that tell why other answers not working with me, and for his answer, as commented to hime, why i want to avoid the way he is doing it. however i am trying to evaluate something also not far, conceptually from all the ansowers here, but until i become sure about the solution, then will mark the closest answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are somehow correct but I doubt they will work with Slick, your id has to be a `Rep` of some parameter and not an `Int`, the best way would be to have an abstract table with and id field and make your concrete table extend that:

```
abstract class RichTable[T](tag: Tag, name: String) extends Table[T](tag, name) {
  val id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
}

class ConcreteTable(tag: Tag) extends RichTable[ConcreteRow](tag, "concrete_table") { ... }
```

Note that I made the id primary key. Now any `TableQuery[T]` with `[T <: RichTable[A], A]` will have access to an id:

```
trait GenericPersistence[T <: RichTable[A], A] {

  val tableReference: TableQuery[T]

  def deleteById(id: Long)(implicit s: Session): Boolean = 
    tableReference.filter(_.id === id).delete == 1

  /* other generic methods ids based */
}
```

For a more complete answers with other methods you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345303/slick-2-0-generic-crud-operations), for Slick 3 it's basically the same.

You can achieve the same result with a trait:

```
trait RichTable[T] {
  self: Table[T] =>

  val id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
}

class ConcreteTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[ConcreteRow](tag, "concrete_table") with RichTable[ConcreteRow]
```

You can decide if you want to implement the id field in the trait or not.

Comment: Yes. thank you, I am trying that, but i want to avoid the inheritance way actually, its somewhat restricted.

Comment: Can we do it without extending RichTable for ConcreteTable

Comment: @ALMEK Would a trait be acceptable? you need to have a common superclass or trait to access the id field, otherwise you have to recur to a structural type has shown in another answer but I would discourage that.

Comment: I admire your contribution, it doesn't consider the case of using (slick code generation),  it will be very boring to extend this trait for all other tables after auto generate them. and if i do it the other way, i am having TableQuery[T] problem.

Comment: I've never done it but you can also [customise your slick generator](https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-customization-example/blob/master/codegen/CustomizedCodeGenerator.scala), maybe on `override table = new Table(_) {...}` you can add a trait, not sure though.

Comment: yea, i actually practiced this way in other languages, however i expected that scala has a simpler way of telling the compiler about object property.

Comment: Should be a better way. which let more freedom of your solution. however i accepted this as an ansower but i am doing it other way, since no a lot of benefits but more restriction

Answer (score 1):

`trait T { val id: Int}` Your data type should extend T.
Are you trying to delete all those for which id=someId?
In that case `filter(_.id === id).foreach(delete)`

Answer (score 1):

Make `T` subtype of the `Entity` trait and declare `id` inside `Entity`

```
 trait Entity {
  val id: Int
}

def del[T <: Entity](id: Int) = TableQuery[T] filter (_.id === id) delete
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> trait Entity {
     |   val id: Int
     | }
defined trait Entity

scala> def foo[T <: Entity](a: T) = a.id
foo: [T <: Entity](a: T)Int
```

Comment: thank you for you very clear answer, but as you see the question is not general as your standard answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use structural types to enforce constraints on a type parameter.

```
case class Thing(id: Int)
def getId[A <: {val id: Int}](a: A):Int = a.id
println(getId(Thing(100)))
```

The result here would be `100`

There are performance implications to this approach however, since structural types use reflections.

Also as Ian noted, you will need to turn on `-language:reflectiveCalls` in your `scalaOptions`.

Comment: You do have to explicitly enable `scala.language.reflectiveCalls` to make this work, though, or the compiler will complain.

Comment: @soote i personally liked your way, just as you see slick case is more dull. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And just for record, I have also tried this, which is seems working, but i not trusted for further solutions in real code so far, since that related to the use case.

```
trait TableModel[T <: ({val id: Rep[Int]}) with Table[U], U]{

    val tq: TableQuery[T]
    def del(id: Int) = tq filter (_.id === id) delete
   ...
}
```